# Python - KeyError: 'Column'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I have a dataset like this:

```
data = {'Price': [1, 4, 5, 100],
        'Year': [20, 21, 19, 18],
        'Mileage': [100, 1500, 1654, 2024],
        'EngineV': [2, 3, 5, 4]}
```

I'm trying to remove outliers with this function:

```
 def remove_outliers(data=data,columns=columns,n_std=3):
        for col in columns:
                   
            mean = data[col].mean()
            sd = data[col].std()
            df = data[(data[col] <= mean+(n_std*sd))]
            
        return data

    df = pd.DataFrame(data.apply(remove_outliers))
```

...but I'm getting this error:

```
KeyError: 'Price'
```

I've tried specifying the data with these, but none resolve the error:

```
columns=data[['Price','Mileage','EngineV','Year']]

columns=("Price","Mileage","EngineV","Year")

columns=data.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3]]
```

Here's the full traceback:

```
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3621, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3620 try:
-> 3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:

File C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:144, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi:41, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: 'Price'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [13], in <module>
      8         df = data[(data[col] <= mean+(n_std*sd))]
     10     return data
---> 11 df = pd.DataFrame(data.apply(remove_outliers))
     12 print("New Shape :", df.shape)

File C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:8839, in DataFrame.apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwargs)
   8828 from pandas.core.apply import frame_apply
   8830 op = frame_apply(
   8831     self,
   8832     func=func,
   (...)
   8837     kwargs=kwargs,
   8838 )
-> 8839 return op.apply().__finalize__(self, method="apply")

File C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:727, in FrameApply.apply(self)
    724 elif self.raw:
    725     return self.apply_raw()
--> 727 return self.apply_standard()

File C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:851, in FrameApply.apply_standard(self)
    850 def apply_standard(self):
--> 851     results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
    853     # wrap results
    854     return self.wrap_results(results, res_index)

File C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:867, in FrameApply.apply_series_generator(self)
    864 with option_context("mode.chained_assignment", None):
    865     for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
    866         # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
--> 867         results[i] = self.f(v)
    868         if isinstance(results[i], ABCSeries):
    869             # If we have a view on v, we need to make a copy because
    870             #  series_generator will swap out the underlying data
    871             results[i] = results[i].copy(deep=False)

Input In [13], in remove_outliers(data, columns, n_std)
      3 def remove_outliers(data=data,columns=columns,n_std=3):
      4     for col in columns:
----> 6         mean = data[col].mean()
      7         sd = data[col].std()
      8         df = data[(data[col] <= mean+(n_std*sd))]

File C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:958, in Series.__getitem__(self, key)
    955     return self._values[key]
    957 elif key_is_scalar:
--> 958     return self._get_value(key)
    960 if is_hashable(key):
    961     # Otherwise index.get_value will raise InvalidIndexError
    962     try:
    963         # For labels that don't resolve as scalars like tuples and frozensets

File C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:1069, in Series._get_value(self, label, takeable)
   1066     return self._values[label]
   1068 # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
-> 1069 loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
   1070 return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)

File C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3623, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:
-> 3623     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3624 except TypeError:
   3625     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3626     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3627     #  the TypeError.
   3628     self._check_indexing_error(key)
```

KeyError: 'Price'

My ultimate goal is to remove the rows with outliers from the whole dataset.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Since `data` is a `dict` where the key is the column name, there shouldn't be a need for setting them separately. And post the full traceback so that we see the failing line.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to transfer from a *dict* to a *DataFrame*, <s>always</s> use the [from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html#pandas-dataframe-from-dict) function

I tried tweaking your code a bit and now it doesn't throw any errors:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Price': [1, 4, 5, 100],
        'Year': [20, 21, 19, 18],
        'Mileage': [100, 1500, 1654, 2024],
        'EngineV': [2, 3, 5, 4]}

def remove_outliers(data, n_std=3):
    for col in data.keys(): # data.keys give list of the all columns names in df
        mean = data[col].mean()
        sd = data[col].std() # throw an error if std receives str in
        data = data.loc[data[col] <= mean+(n_std*sd)]
        
    return data

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data) # use pd.DataFrame.from_dict
new_df = remove_outliers(data=df, n_std=3)
```

Comment: Why "always use `from_dict`"? Can't we just use `df = pd.DataFrame(data)` ?

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you! Although I'm curious to understand @VladimirFokow 's question

Comment: You are right @vladimir-fokow
But I learned to always specify what the DataFrame will be created from, there is also a convenient **orient** parameter :) *(I corrected the answer, thank you!)*